# jQuery noob: change border color of element on hover of another element

Tags: jquery, html, css, onhover

I'd try to explain what I mean, but there is an easier way: [click here for jsfiddle exampl](http://jsfiddle.net/NwGW6/)e.

Basically I want the border color of the div `rfrsh_btn` to change when `productOptionsMenu` is hovered over.

I'm using jQuery with the .noConflict var because this site also uses Prototype.

jQuery:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(".productOptionsMenu").hover(
    function () {
        $j(#rfrsh_btn).css({"border-color":"#85c222"});
    };
);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(".productOptionsMenu").hover(
    // hover begin (mouse-in)
    function () {
        $j("#rfrsh_btn").css({"border-color": "#85c222"});
    },
    // hover end (mouse-out)
    function () {
        $j("#rfrsh_btn").css({"border-color": ""});
    }
);
```

Instead of `css()` I recommend using `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, respectively.

Comment: Haha yeah, well the code is in place within the .tpl file in between literal tags, when I hover over the element, the border color doesn't change. The othee jQuery function works perfectly, and when I try to change the  target element to change, it doesn't change.

Comment: @Kyle: Time to open developer tools and find out what's happening, since the above code itself obviously works.

Comment: Going through that now. It will be interesting to find out why it won't work.

Comment: Found the solution, I closed the function `});` too soon, fixed now, all working! Thanks Tomalak!

Comment: @Kyle: I thought it must be something simple. :-)

Answer (score 1):

looks correct to me, maybe just add the missing quotes in

```
$j("#rfrsh_btn").css({"border-color":"#85c222"});
```

Comment: you might also have to re-instantiate the $j var inside the anonymous function

Comment: If `$j` is defined at the global level, then no.

Comment: Logical conclusion: You don't have to re-instantiate `$` (or `jQuery`, for that matter) either - they're always there because they have been defined at the global object.

Comment: It is defined in another function in the same script tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$j('.productOptionsMenu ').mouseover(function(){
  $j("#rfrsh_btn").css({"border-color":"#0000ff"});
});
```