# How to toggle the color of the border onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a panel which is of class panel-body. It has a default color blue. I have a button as well. When I click the button, I want to change the color of the border of the panel from blue to green and back to blue again (some transition would be even better). How can I achieve that with jquery and css.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps provide some code that we can help with rather than expect an answer straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this using `jQuery`

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.panel-body').toggleClass('panelBorderColor')
})
```

```css
.panel-body {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: teal;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.panelBorderColor {
    border-color: green;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body"></div>
<button class="btn">Click</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(".panel-body").hover(
    // hover begin (mouse-in)
    function () {
        $j("#rfrsh_btn").css({"border-color": "green"});
    },
    // hover end (mouse-out)
    function () {
        $j("#rfrsh_btn").css({"border-color": "blue"});
    }
);
```

This is based on this answer: [jQuery noob: change border color of element on hover of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764147/jquery-noob-change-border-color-of-element-on-hover-of-another-element)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$("yourbutton").click(function(){
   $("yourpanel").css({"border-color": "green", "transition": "all 1.2s"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggleClass

CSS

```
.bg-color { width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: yellow; border:solid 1px green; }
.bg-color.green {border:solid 1px red; }
```

JS

```
$(".bg-color").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("green");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="bg-color">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a the `.closest()` jQuery method to traverse UP the hierarchy to find the nearest `div` *(or, you could use `.closest('.panel-body')` to specify the nearest parent with class of `parent-body`)* ***above that specific button.*** That is, using `$('.panel-body')` will find ALL panel-body divs.

To provide a transition effect, you can use the `transition` CSS directive. Use it thus:

```
transition: [transition-property] [transition-duration] [transition-timing-function] [transition-delay];
```

Finally, we can use `setTimeout()` to delay the next instruction by a number of seconds -- ***Important: ensure the `setTimeout()` delay*** (2800ms) ***is longer than the transition delay*** *(2s i.e. 2000ms)* .

```js
$('.panel-body button').click(function(){
  $this = $(this)
  $this.closest('div').addClass('brdGreen');
  setTimeout(function(){
      $this.closest('div').removeClass('brdGreen');
  },2800);
});
```

```css
.panel-body{
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  outline:blue;
  XXXtransition: border 2s ease-out 0s; /* remove XXX to see effect */
}
.brdGreen{
  border:2px solid green;
  XXXtransition: border 2s ease-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
    <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

#### References:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55894602/1447509